# What is a "cell" in group theory?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

A theorem says: "Let $X$ be a $G$-set. For $x_1,x_2\in X$, let $x_1 \sim x_2 \iff \exists g\in G$ such that $gx_1 = x_2$."

A definition says: "Let $X$ be a $G$-set. Each cell in the partition of $\sim$ in the above mentioned theorem is an Orbit in $X$ under $G$. If $x\in X$, the cell containing $x$ is the orbit of $x$. We let this cell be $Gx$.

What is a cell? (It probably says somewhere in my textbook, but I couldn't find it and googling it turned out to be not a bit of a nightmare.)

(This is from "A first course in abstract algebra", 7th edition by John B. Fraleigh. Thm 16.14 and Def 16.15)

Comment: The orbit, $Gx$, is just the set $\{y\in X : \exists g\in G y=gx\}$. They might use the word "cell" for some reason, but I've never seen that terminology myself. If you are still sufficiently interested after knowing this, please edit your question to include a reference to where you're seeing this terminology used.

Comment: From context it looks like "cell" probably means "equivalence class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a cell refers to an equivalence class of the partition. The equivalence class of $x\in X$ is the set of all $y\in X$ equivalent to $x$, i.e., $[x] = \{ gx\mid g\in G\}$.

Comment: So the orbit of $x$ is just then the equivalence class containing $x$, right?

Comment: Indeed, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

When having doubt in a terminology, one could look it up in the "index" section of the book. Fraleigh tells you it is on page 6 of his book:

> [image]

Comment: The index section of Fraleigh's book is beyond horrid though. I've tried looking up 10-12 things mentioned in his book, that aren't referenced in the index.